# Cannot find symbol class but the class is there

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote this little code to create a spring web application. When i compile that the code it gave me the Cannot find symbol error. I have the class declared and imported properly but can't seem to solve it. the code won't compile either. please help

```
package com.homework3.cis3368.Main.Controller;

import com.homework3.cis3368.Main.Models.ZooManagementRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
ZooManagementRepo zooRepo;


@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView homepage(){
    ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("index");
    home.addObject("list", zooRepo.findAll());

    return home;
    }

}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Error:(4, 41) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ZooManagementRepo
location: package com.homework3.cis3368.Main.Models

Error:(15, 5) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ZooManagementRepo
location: class com.homework3.cis3368.Main.Controller.MainController
```

The project structure looks like this

```
main
 java
   com.homework3.cis3368.Main
     Controller (package)
       MainController
     Models (package)
       ZooManagement
       ZooManagementRepo(interface file)
     Homework3Application
```

Comment: The `ZooManagementRepo` is probably in the wrong directory.  Alternatively, the package name you are using here for `ZooManagementRepo` could be wrong.

Comment: please share the code and the project structure.

Comment: i added the structure

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: package names should be written in all-lowercase.

Comment: that didn't change anything, i refactor the package to lowercase and still get errors